# Duplicate config code problem for all spring microservices

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, apache-zookeeper

Is there a way to create a spring configuration class and use it to all my microservices?

Right now I have to copy a duplicate config class to all microservices. And if there are changes , I have to make them in all modules.

I use the apache zookeeper for centralize my configurations in single place. For setting authentication details on connection to zookeeper server I have to create a new bean for CuratorFramework class in spring @Configuration in any microservices that keep their configs on the zookeeper.

Comment: Your question is a little vague, but you can create your own auto-configuration module https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-developing-auto-configuration

Comment: @MarcosBarbero For example I have a custom config for set ACL on the apache curator for connecting to my apache zookeeper server. I have to have this config for all microservice modules that use the zookeeper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

- Create a module with a configuration (maven, gradle managed, whatever). Add all common beans to this module for reuse. It will be a kind of "infra".
- Optionally add a `spring.factories` file to automatically "load" the configuration
- In Microservices (each of them should be in a different module) add a dependency on that common module.

If you've added `spring.factories` - the configuration will be loaded automatically, if you didn't you'll have to import this configuration explicitly in each module. But in any case you won't need to duplicate code.

There are many tutorials / threads in SO about spring factories, so in case you're not familiar with this feature - you can read [here for example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M5/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

If a system has lots of common stuff and stuff that changes often it's a monolith. Maybe your split to microservices is not the best approach.

Regarding shared common stuff you get 3 choices:

- Copy/paste (like you do for now)
- Break out library (each microservice has a dependency to a common module)
- Isolate stuff in his own microservice

Remember that DRY must be strict inside one microservice but can be relaxed between microservices.